# Хочу использовать список внутри класса для накопления скачанной информации в Python, но он почему-то не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
import urllib.request
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.remotedata = [] #Тут по идеи должна копиться информация

    def multiloader(self, link, agent, cookie):
        p = Process(target=MyProcess.loader,
                    args=(self, link, agent, cookie))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        return self.remotedata #если заменить return на print вернёт пустой список
    
    def loader(self, link, agent, cookie):
        """For more info visit:
        https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html
        """
        print('Download url:', link)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', agent), ('Cookie', cookie)]
        remotefile = opener.open(link)
        remotedata = remotefile.read().decode('utf-8')
        remotefile.close()
        self.remotedata.append(remotedata)
        #print(self.remotedata) #тут print возвращает список со скачанной html страницей
```

Когда вызываю функцию multiloader из другого модуля, страница скачивается, но возвращается пустой список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Процесс, в отличие от потока, получает отдельную копию данных породившего его процесса. Поэтому то, что происходит с данными порождённого процесса, вы так просто не можете получить обратно в том месте, где этот процесс породили, просто вот обратившись к своим переменным. У него своя копия данных, а у вас своя. Поэтому в ваших данных пусто, хотя у порождённого процесса там что-то есть. Вы должны в явном виде вернуть эти данные из процесса.

Ну либо пользуйтесь потоками, а не процессами. Потоки разделяют данные между собой и вы их можете получить из переменных класса так, как вы тут хотите.

Comment: Ok, понял, буду дальше книжку читать. :) С Pool.map что-то рабочее получилось, но оно 1 аргумент принимает, а мне нужно передать 4.

Comment: @Ilya Так вы в этом одном аргументе можете передать что угодно, если я правильно помню. Хоть кортеж со многими переменными, хоть что угодно вообще :)  Но помните, что если данных много будет передаваться туда и обратно, то сериализация данных и порождение потоков может съесть всю выгоду от многопоточности %)  А так то `Pool.map` вещь хорошая.